# Remote-SSH resulted in an error command opensshremote.openEmptyWindow not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

Remote-SSH resulted in an error command opensshremote.openEmptyWindow not found.
I am on Arch Linux, vscode-oss from community repository package `code` version 1.64.
How to fix?

```
> pacman -Ss vscode
community/code 1.64.0-1 [installed]
    The Open Source build of Visual Studio Code (vscode) editor
```

[image]

Comment: It seems vscodium (vscode-oss) is not supported by proprietary tools from Microsoft. ;(

Comment: Not supported proprietary software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround i installed extensions via regular VSCode,
then renamed/symlinked `~/.vscode` to `~/.vscodium`, and it works.